# sql with one count() another count() in LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, count, left-join, distinct

having:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(MakeModel) as `count`
FROM (`table_a`)
GROUP BY `MakeModel`
ORDER BY `count` DESC
```

Works fine for me (count = 2)
extend this query with a LEFT JOIN like this:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(distinct b.rating) as ratings
FROM (`table_a`)
LEFT JOIN `model_ratings` AS b ON `b`.`MakeModel` = `table_a`.`MakeModel`
GROUP BY `table_a`.`MakeModel`
```

Also works fine (ratings = 3),
but combine the 2 counts like this:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(table_a.MakeModel) as `count`, COUNT(distinct b.rating) as ratings
FROM (`table_a`)
LEFT JOIN `model_ratings` AS b ON `b`.`MakeModel` = `table_a`.`MakeModel`
GROUP BY `table_a`.`MakeModel`
ORDER BY `count` DESC
```

then (count= 6 ) and (ratings = 3).

So count becomes ('count' times 'ratings').

But I need (count= 2 ) and (ratings = 3)

What am I missing here?

Comment: Don't you see 6 rows when your run the query? What makes you think `count` will be 2 when there are, in fact, 6 `MakeModel`s? Maybe a reasonable solution is to do `COUNT(distinct MakeModel)`

Comment: first query counts the amount of groups. Right?
There are a lot more then 6 MakeModels. But 2 times a specific MakeModel.

Comment: your query seems fine, may you post your table structure for clarification?

Comment: Hm, not sure I understand. Can you add a picture of the output of the query or display the data in some other way?

Comment: 1. query = http://awesomescreenshot.com/0aa2158x21
2. query = http://awesomescreenshot.com/095215913e
3. wrong query = http://awesomescreenshot.com/07921594c9

Comment: @TNT_Larsn My intuition tells me that for each `MakeModel` you have multiple matching `model_rating`s, but hard for me to be sure because I honestly still don't understand `GROUP BY`. Remove the `GROUP BY` and take a look at the results. I bet you'll see six `Beechcraft 1900D`s.

Comment: @roliu
removing `GROUP BY` results in this: [link](http://awesomescreenshot.com/07f215fa88)
ratings of all `MakeModel` where added (8) also all `zaehler` where added (456)
and only one row is shown

Comment: @roliu
Also see 1.query [link](http://awesomescreenshot.com/0aa2158x21) for the correct amount of `Beechcraft 1900D`s
YES THERE ARE multiple matching `model_rating`s

Comment: I Think I have to `COUNT( DISTINCT c.rating )`  -> then `group` the `LEFT JOIN` results in the first place

Comment: solution: [link](http://awesomescreenshot.com/0a3215gtea)

Comment: It's quite late but I'm actually incredibly confused how there was only one row in the query when you removed the `GROUP BY`. Regardless, if you want to remove the duplicate `MakeModels` that resulted from your original `LEFT JOIN` then your solution works... but I feel like `COUNT(distinct MakeModel)` would work as well and is quite a bit clearer. Maybe I'm misunderstanding your data schema. Anyways, glad you found a solution.

Comment: Found out by myself
COUNT() and GROUP inside the LEFT JOIN first

    SELECT *, COUNT(table_a.MakeModel) as `count`, b.rating as ratings
    FROM (`table_a`)
    LEFT JOIN (
       SELECT MakeModel, COUNT(distinct rating)
       FROM `model_ratings`
       GROUP BY MakeModel
       ) AS b ON `b`.`MakeModel` = `table_a`.`MakeModel`

    GROUP BY `table_a`.`MakeModel`
    ORDER BY `count` DESC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out by myself
COUNT() and GROUP inside the LEFT JOIN first

```
SELECT *, COUNT(table_a.MakeModel) as `count`, b.rating as ratings
FROM (`table_a`)
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT MakeModel, COUNT(distinct rating)
   FROM `model_ratings`
   GROUP BY MakeModel
   ) AS b ON `b`.`MakeModel` = `table_a`.`MakeModel`

GROUP BY `table_a`.`MakeModel`
ORDER BY `count` DESC
```